Microsoft Entra External ID - Custom authentication extensions - Get email on AttributeCollectionStart for google provider
I'm trying to integrate Microsoft Entra External ID for our Signup flow.
I have created a custom Rest API for handling the AttributeCollectionStart event (event from the Custom Authentication Extensions).
On this REST API, I want to check if the user who is in the signup flow is authorized to use the application (we have a list in database with authorized email address), then pre-fill the attributes from this database by searching the user using the email address.
When registering a user with email address, the flow is working well, since I'm able to get the email address from this field:
"identities": [
                {
                    "signInType": "emailAddress",
                    "issuer": "myapp.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "issuerAssignedId": "fakeMail@provider.com"
                }
            ]

The problem is when registering with Google Provider, I'm only getting a google identifier (I think it is, I'm not sure) :
"Identities": [
            {
                "Issuer": "google.com",
                "IssuerAssignedId": "117008053156718551476",
                "SignInType": "federated"
            }
        ]

Is there a possibility to retreive the email in the signup process ?
Is Microsoft Graph will work for this use case ? (never used it).
It work with default provider (email), but not google provider.

Alternatively, you can make use of Microsoft Graph API to retrieve email of user. Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
